# Function to swap elements from two arrays and create a new array from this two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, arraylist

How can I write a function swap that takes 3 arguments, two arrays and a number and swaps two items in these arrays at the specified position/index which is the third argument,and then return these two arrays inside another array?

I tried this

```
function swap (arr1, arr2, pos) {
    var x = arr1[pos];
    arr2.splice(pos, 1, x);
    var y = arr2[pos];
    arr1.splice(pos, 1, y)
    var newArray = arr1 + arr2;
}
```

But is not working. I just get undefined in the console.

Comment: please add return newArray = arr1 + arr2; inside swap function so that function will return new array

Comment: What exactly `and then return these two arrays inside another array` mean? An array of arrays or an array of concatenated arrays. Besides `[] + []` works this way : Calls `toString()` method of each element and then concatenate them as string. So the final result will be a string not array.

Answer (score 1):

```
function swap (arr1, arr2, pos) {
    var x = arr1[pos];
    var y = arr2[pos];
    
    arr1[pos] = y;
    arr2[pos] = x;
    
    return [arr1, arr2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using this nefty trick

```js
const array1 = [1,2,3];
const array2 = [4,5,6];

function swap (arr1, arr2, pos) {
    [arr1[pos],arr2[pos]] = [arr2[pos],arr1[pos]];
    return [...arr1, ...arr2];
}

console.log(swap(array1, array2, 1));
```

Comment: Omg Reda thanks a lot! That works and is great!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write return at the end

```
function swap (arr1, arr2, pos) {
    var x = arr1[pos];
    arr2 = arr2.splice(pos, 1, x);
    var y = arr2[pos];
    arr1 = arr1.splice(pos, 1, y)
    return arr1 + arr2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Majid! But I get 312 with that, some kind of operation with all the array elements, but no worries is already solved! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code... I hope this serves your problem

```js
let arr1 = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
let arr2 = [21, 22, 23, 24, 25];
let pos = 2;
function swap(arr1, arr2, pos) {
    var x = arr1[pos];
    var y = arr2[pos];
    arr2.splice(pos, 1, x);
    arr1.splice(pos, 1, y)
    var newArray = [...arr1, ...arr2];
    return newArray
}
let x = swap(arr1, arr2, pos);
console.log(x)
```

Output

```
[ 11, 12, 23, 14, 15, 21, 22, 13, 24, 25 ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Selva! That is exactly what a was trying to do. It works wonderfully.